# How we dynamically create and use storyboards for rotating a grid along yaxis

Tags: animation, rotation, storyboard, uwp

I am developing a UWP app.

I am trying to rotate a grid dynamically by creating a storyboard at runtime. However, I could not find BeginAnimation() method or TargetTyepe/TargetName property in StoryBoard through which I can animate my grid.

Could you please suggest me a possible workaround for the same? If possible, please share the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Storyboard in code like this:

**XAML**

```xml
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

**CS**

```cs
var sb = new Storyboard();

var anim = new DoubleAnimation();
Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, MyGrid);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)");
anim.From = 0;
anim.To = 360;
anim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
sb.Children.Add(anim);

sb.Begin();
```

Alternatively, you can `x:Name` the `RenderTransform` instead and set that as the target directly, instead of targeting it indirectly through `MyGrid`.